# How to Remove the empty Space at the Right of my Webpage?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is an assignment to design a simple Responsive web page using Twitter Bootstrap where a Collapsible Menu Button appears only on extra small Devices and Just The brand Name on Larger devices.And I think I achieved that goal.

But the problem is this annoying white space towards the right of my web page,across all devices(I tested using Chrome Developer Tools).

Any Suggestions to remove the Space,as it makes the web page more compact and Nice to view.Thanks in advance. I've attached an image of the white space and a link to my code.

CSS Code,

```
/*html
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}*/
body{
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}
/*Header Section*/
#brand-name{
    position: relative;
    bottom:20px;
    left: 1px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav-LLC{
    border-radius: 0px;
}


}
#nav-list{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#nav-list a {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e1e6ed;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
#nav-list a:hover{
    background-color: #96d4e8;
}
/*End of Header Section*/

/* Only for Extra Small Devices*/

@media (max-width: 500px){
    h1{
        font-size: 7vw;
    }
    h2{
        font-size: 7vw;
    }
}

/*Start of Body Section*/ 
h2{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-color: #0b0821;
}
.row section{

}
.row section p{
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: #e1e6ed;
}
h4{
    position: relative;
    left: 40%;*/
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #0b2730;
    /*background-color: #e1e6ed;
    margin: 0px;*/
}
/*End of Body Section*/
```

HTML Code,

```
<header>
    <nav id="nav-LLC" class="navbar navbar-default ">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                    <a  id="brand-name" href="index.html" ><h1> Food,LLC </h1></a>
                </div>

                <div class="button-class">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapsable" aria-expanded="false" >
                    <span class="sr-only"> Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> <!--Icon Bar is three lines in the icon-->
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

            </div><!-- Navbar-header -->
            <section class="visible-xs">
            <div id="nav-collapsable" class="collapse navbar-collapse" >
                <ul id="nav-list"  class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#chicken"><span>Chicken</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#beef"><span>Beef</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#sushi"><span>Sushi</span></a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="#"><span>Cookies</span><br></a></li>-->
                </ul>
            </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>



<div class="container">
<h2>Our Menu</h2>
<div class="row">
<section id="chicken" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<h4>Chicken</h4>
<p>Do qui nulla et ullamco ut quis excepteur nulla amet. Eiusmod dolore tempor deserunt velit in nulla dolore ut duis dolor. Lorem ipsum duis ea ut occaecat cupidatat sint incididunt laborum ut duis ea cillum excepteur nulla velit ut. Veniam adipisicing proident esse tempor aliquip non nulla laboris esse dolore fugiat nostrud eu nulla consequat ut qui ad. Amet ad sint pariatur aliquip tempor mollit labore minim voluptate fugiat non.<a class="visible-xs" href="#nav-LLC" ><br>Back to top</a></p>
</section>

<section id="beef" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<h4>Beef</h4>
<p>Do qui nulla et ullamco ut quis excepteur nulla amet. Eiusmod dolore tempor deserunt velit in nulla dolore ut duis dolor. Lorem ipsum duis ea ut occaecat cupidatat sint incididunt laborum ut duis ea cillum excepteur nulla velit ut. Veniam adipisicing proident esse tempor aliquip non nulla laboris esse dolore fugiat nostrud eu nulla consequat ut qui ad. Amet ad sint pariatur aliquip tempor mollit labore minim voluptate fugiat non.<a class="visible-xs" href="#nav-LLC" ><br>Back to top</a></p>
</section>

<section id="sushi" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<h4>Sushi</h4>
<p>Do qui nulla et ullamco ut quis excepteur nulla amet. Eiusmod dolore tempor deserunt velit in nulla dolore ut duis dolor. Lorem ipsum duis ea ut occaecat cupidatat sint incididunt laborum ut duis ea cillum excepteur nulla velit ut. Veniam adipisicing proident esse tempor aliquip non nulla laboris esse dolore fugiat nostrud eu nulla consequat ut qui ad. Amet ad sint pariatur aliquip tempor mollit labore minim voluptate fugiat non.<a class="visible-xs" href="#nav-LLC" ><br>Back to top</a></p>
</section>

</div>
</div>


<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

`Link to HTMl and CSS code` https://jsfiddle.net/w5v6yr9q/

`link to the image` https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieRok.png

**Edit**: Thank you so much people!! Learned something new today!

Comment: seems you forget attachment :)

Comment: It's because of text chicken, beef and sushi which are in h4 tag, instead of giving left: 40%; try text-align: center;

Comment: the body element has standard padding/margin for most browsers. Add: body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

Comment: @Gerard tries that.No changes.The white space increases with decrease in Device width.

Comment: @programmingArrow Thank you Very Much!!! that fixed it!! But can I know why it happened and how can I insert the Titles without this side-effect.I'm a a newbie :))

Comment: I think there's few answers to your last comment @VigneshGunasekaran answer by Neo Genesis will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to know is there are default CSS values for HTML elements in the web, which are hidden a bit in the developer tools.
 [https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)

**For your example you need to add two things**: First remove the default margin for the `body`. This will remove the white gaps to the edges of the viewport.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Second your `h4` are pulled to the right because of `left: 40%`, to center them flexible and on all viewports take a look at the folliwing code:

```
h4 {
    position: relative /* remove this */;
    left: 40%; /* remove this */

    text-align: center; /* add this */
}
```

Please keep in mind it is a better approach to style on a class like `.center-headline` and add your needed styles there. Then you just need to copy & paste without worries.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!! I'll keep that in Mind!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line in CSS

CSS

```
h4{
left:40%;/*remove this*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your jsfiddle, the  tags under the sections (Chicken, Beef, Sushi). You have h4 css with position relative and "left: 40%;".

Give all your h4 tags a class("menu-title" for instance).
and give the CSS below

```
.menu-title {
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @VigneshGunasekaran
"position: relative;" & "left: 40%;" means "move this element 40% from the left of the parent element's total width". By setting it to "position: static;" it disables the "top, right, left, bottom" properties.

reference: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Div like this :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12"><!--  Add this Div-->
    <h2>Our Menu</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <section id="chicken" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <h4>Chicken</h4>
      <!-- following codes -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see your H4 styles below:

```
h4{
    position: relative;
    /* left: 40%;*/ /* this is the issue */
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #0b2730;
  text-align:center; /* if you want to center the text */
    /*background-color: #e1e6ed;
    margin: 0px;*/
}
```

Comment: That worked!! thank you very much !Next time I'll follow this!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/w5v6yr9q/2/

```css
/*html
{
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}*/
body{
 font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}
/*Header Section*/
#brand-name{
 position: relative;
 bottom:20px;
 left: 1px;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.nav-LLC{
 border-radius: 0px;
}


}
#nav-list{
 margin-top: 10px;
}
#nav-list a {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e1e6ed;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
#nav-list a:hover{
 background-color: #96d4e8;
}
/*End of Header Section*/

/* Only for Extra Small Devices*/

@media (max-width: 500px){
 h1{
  font-size: 7vw;
 }
 h2{
  font-size: 7vw;
 }
}

/*Start of Body Section*/ 
h2{
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-color: #0b0821;
}
.row section{
 
}
.row section p{
 text-align: justify;
 background-color: #e1e6ed;
}
h4{
 position: relative;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #0b2730;
 /*background-color: #e1e6ed;
 margin: 0px;*/
}
/*End of Body Section*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <nav id="nav-LLC" class="navbar navbar-default ">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
     <a  id="brand-name" href="index.html" ><h1> Food,LLC </h1></a>
    </div>
     
    <div class="button-class">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapsable" aria-expanded="false" >
     <span class="sr-only"> Toggle Navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span> <!--Icon Bar is three lines in the icon-->
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
    </div>
  
   </div><!-- Navbar-header -->
   <section class="visible-xs">
   <div id="nav-collapsable" class="collapse navbar-collapse" >
    <ul id="nav-list"  class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#chicken"><span>Chicken</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#beef"><span>Beef</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#sushi"><span>Sushi</span></a></li>
     <!--<li><a href="#"><span>Cookies</span><br></a></li>-->
    </ul>
   </div>
   </section>
  </div>
 </nav>
</header>



<div class="container">
<h2>Our Menu</h2>
<div class="row">
<section id="chicken" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<h4 class="text-center">Chicken</h4>
<p>Do qui nulla et ullamco ut quis excepteur nulla amet. Eiusmod dolore tempor deserunt velit in nulla dolore ut duis dolor. Lorem ipsum duis ea ut occaecat cupidatat sint incididunt laborum ut duis ea cillum excepteur nulla velit ut. Veniam adipisicing proident esse tempor aliquip non nulla laboris esse dolore fugiat nostrud eu nulla consequat ut qui ad. Amet ad sint pariatur aliquip tempor mollit labore minim voluptate fugiat non.<a class="visible-xs" href="#nav-LLC" ><br>Back to top</a></p>
</section>

<section id="beef" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<h4 class="text-center">Beef</h4>
<p>Do qui nulla et ullamco ut quis excepteur nulla amet. Eiusmod dolore tempor deserunt velit in nulla dolore ut duis dolor. Lorem ipsum duis ea ut occaecat cupidatat sint incididunt laborum ut duis ea cillum excepteur nulla velit ut. Veniam adipisicing proident esse tempor aliquip non nulla laboris esse dolore fugiat nostrud eu nulla consequat ut qui ad. Amet ad sint pariatur aliquip tempor mollit labore minim voluptate fugiat non.<a class="visible-xs" href="#nav-LLC" ><br>Back to top</a></p>
</section>

<section id="sushi" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<h4 class="text-center">Sushi</h4>
<p>Do qui nulla et ullamco ut quis excepteur nulla amet. Eiusmod dolore tempor deserunt velit in nulla dolore ut duis dolor. Lorem ipsum duis ea ut occaecat cupidatat sint incididunt laborum ut duis ea cillum excepteur nulla velit ut. Veniam adipisicing proident esse tempor aliquip non nulla laboris esse dolore fugiat nostrud eu nulla consequat ut qui ad. Amet ad sint pariatur aliquip tempor mollit labore minim voluptate fugiat non.<a class="visible-xs" href="#nav-LLC" ><br>Back to top</a></p>
</section>

</div>
</div>



<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Remove **left:40%;** from `h4` in `CSS`

Instead use `bootstrap` class **text-center** in `HTML` `h4` tag. It's a clean approach.